# segmentation fault after installation piwik 2.9.1

Tags: apache, php-5.4, matomo

I just downloaded on this website the latest version of Piwik, I install, everything works the first time.

But I arrived on the main page right after installation, some wigets not displayed, others do.

> [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25089 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25092 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25093 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25095 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25096 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25098 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25099 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25101 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25102 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25103 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25203 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25204 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25207 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   [Thu Nov 27 20:07:21 2014] [notice] child pid 25209 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

That is very hassle ...

I just changed server, is it possible I'm missing some packages on php or other? (my web site works however) any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it helps other people: this error is due to APC 3.1.9...

upgrade APC to last release (3.1.13) allowed me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing segfaults as well with Piwik 2.9.1. Centos 6, PHP 5.5.19 with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev. Replacing APC with a newer version is only taking away the symptoms. Apparently there is something in the Piwik code triggering segfaults with opcode cachers. I will try a downgrade to Piwik 2.9.0.

Comment: After the downgrade to Piwik 2.9.0 it did not happen again. There is a French report in the Piwik forums now as well: http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?8,122397